# If every closed curve on a surface has zero total torsion, then the surface is totally umbilic

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, curves, submanifold

Let $\Sigma$ be an oriented, simply connected surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, let $\xi$ be its unit normal, and let $\alpha$ be a a smooth curve in $\Sigma$.

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10231-019-00874-5), the authors prove that, if every closed curve $\alpha$ has vanishing total torsion, i.e., if
$$
\int_{\alpha} \tau = 0 \quad \text{for all closed curves $\alpha$},
$$
then $\Sigma$ is totally umbilic. (In fact, they prove a stronger statement by considering a Riemannian ambient space.)

I am having a hard time understanding a step in their proof of Lemma 2, which establishes the said result.

After proving that the integral of the geodesic torsion $\tau_{g}$ over any closed curve $\alpha$ vanishes, they claim that *continuity forces the geodesic torsion to vanish identically*; see text after equation (26) in the picture below.

I am not sure why continuity is invoked here. I agree that, if $\nabla_{X}\xi$ and $X$ are not parallel at $p$, then they remain not parallel in a neighborhood of $p$, but **how can one then conclude that every closed curve around $p$ has $\tau_{g} =0$?**

[image]